# Feature dependencies in the Feature Selection Tree in Wix

Tags: wix, wix3.9

Is there any way to force a particular feature to be installed if another feature is selected in the feature selection tree?  That is without having the features be children of their dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this should be possible, if you use the Condition element under a Feature element, you can control the feature install level from a condition.

```
    <Feature Id="MyDependentFeature">
      <Condition Level="1">(NOT INSTALLED AND &MyMasterFeature=3) OR (INSTALLED AND !MyMasterFeature=3)</Condition> 
    </Feature>

    <Feature Id="MyMasterFeature"> 
    </Feature>
```

A couple things to explain here:

- `Condition Level="1"` tells Wix to set the parent Feature install level to 1 (Install) ([Info](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/condition.html))
- `(NOT INSTALLED AND &MyMasterFeature=3)` If the product is not already installed, and the requested action of MyMasterFeature is Install
- `(INSTALLED AND !MyMasterFeature=3)` If the product is already installed, and the install state of MyMasterFeature is Installed. ([Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(VS.85).aspx))

Comment: This will not work because the feature states are not initialized at the moment the conditions are evaluated.